# How to show glyphicon icon in kendo window title?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-window

I am trying to show an icon on kendo window title. But I am not able to do it. The code I am trying is showing the whole html. I think whatever I pass it in title, it takes as string. Can someone help me please.

```html
<div id="dialog"></div>

<script>
    $("#dialog").kendoWindow({
        title: '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>Customer details'
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try editing the HTML using jQuery.

Something like this (untested):

```
var title = "<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>Customer details"
var window = $("#dialog").data("kendoWindow");
window.wrapper.find('.k-window-title').html(title)
```

Comment: This did worked. Thanks Nic. But I was also looking for using something directly to the title configuration rather than changing the title after its been created.

Comment: As far as I know Kendo UI doesn't support that.